# RunLoop vs DispatchQueue as Scheduler

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, nsrunloop, combine

When using new Combine framework you can specify the scheduler on which to receive elements from the publisher.

Is there a big difference between `RunLoop.main` and `DispatchQueue.main` in this case when assigning publisher to UI element? The first one returns the run loop of the main thread and the second queue associated with the main thread.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've posted the similar question on the Swift Forum. I encourage you to see the discussion https://forums.swift.org/t/runloop-main-or-dispatchqueue-main-when-using-combine-scheduler/26635.

I just copy and paste the answer from **Philippe_Hausler**

> RunLoop.main as a Scheduler ends up calling RunLoop.main.perform whereas DispatchQueue.main calls DispatchQueue.main.async to do work, for practical purposes they are nearly isomorphic. The only real differential is that the RunLoop call ends up being executed in a different spot in the RunLoop callouts whereas the DispatchQueue variant will perhaps execute immediately if optimizations in libdispatch kick in. In reality you should never really see a difference tween the two.
>
> RunLoop should be when you have a dedicated thread with a RunLoop running, DispatchQueue can be any queue scenario (and for the record please avoid running RunLoops in DispatchQueues, it causes some really gnarly resource usage...). Also it is worth noting that the DispatchQueue used as a scheduler must always be serial to adhere to the contracts of Combine's operators.

Answer (score 85):

There actually is a big difference between using `RunLoop.main` as a `Scheduler` and using `DispatchQueue.main` as a `Scheduler`:

- `RunLoop.main` runs callbacks only when the main run loop is running in the `.default` mode, which is **not** the mode used when tracking touch and mouse events. If you use `RunLoop.main` as a `Scheduler`, your events **will not be delivered** while the user is in the middle of a touch or drag.
- `DispatchQueue.main` runs callbacks in all of the `.common` modes, including the modes used when tracking touch and mouse events. If you use `DispatchQueue.main`, your events **will be delivered** while the use user in the middle of a touch or drag.

#### Details

We can see the implementation of `RunLoop`'s conformance to `Scheduler` in [`Schedulers+RunLoop.swift`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/b5570a1aa923d18f5b7a28b06ea2a7424ba65e3b/stdlib/public/Darwin/Foundation/Schedulers%2BRunLoop.swift). In particular, here's how it implements `schedule(options:_:)`:

> ```
>     public func schedule(options: SchedulerOptions?,
>                          _ action: @escaping () -> Void) {
>         self.perform(action)
>     }
> ```

This uses the `RunLoop` `perform(_:)` method, which is the Objective-C method `-[NSRunLoop performBlock:]`. The `performBlock:` method schedules the block to run in the **default** run loop mode only. (This is not documented.)

UIKit and AppKit run the run loop in the default mode when idle. But, in particular, when tracking a user interaction (like a touch or a mouse button press), they run the run loop in a different, non-default mode. So a Combine pipeline that uses `receive(on: RunLoop.main)` **will not** deliver signals while the user is touching or dragging.

We can see the implementation of `DispatchQueue`'s conformance to `Scheduler` in [Schedulers+DispatchQueue.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/2eb460de4d675a0947215bc1878bb61f1a3dcd49/stdlib/public/Darwin/Dispatch/Schedulers%2BDispatchQueue.swift). Here's how it implements `schedule(options:_:)`:

> ```
>     public func schedule(options: SchedulerOptions?, _ action: @escaping () -> Void) {
>         let qos = options?.qos ?? .unspecified
>         let flags = options?.flags ?? []
>         
>         if let group = options?.group {
>             // Distinguish on the group because it appears to not be a call-through like the others. This may need to be adjusted.
>             self.async(group: group, qos: qos, flags: flags, execute: action)
>         } else {
>             self.async(qos: qos, flags: flags, execute: action)
>         }
>     }
> ```

So the block gets added to the queue using a standard GCD method, [async(group:qos:flags:execute:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2016098-async). Under what circumstances are blocks on the main queue executed? In a normal UIKit or AppKit app, the main run loop is responsible for draining the main queue. We can find the run loop implementation in [`CFRunLoop.c`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/7c8f145c834b3a97499fec12d67499eef825a3a4/CoreFoundation/RunLoop.subproj/CFRunLoop.c#L2686). The important function is `__CFRunLoopRun`, which is much too big to quote in its entirety. Here are [the lines of interest](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/7c8f145c834b3a97499fec12d67499eef825a3a4/CoreFoundation/RunLoop.subproj/CFRunLoop.c#L2697):

> ```
> #if __HAS_DISPATCH__
>     __CFPort dispatchPort = CFPORT_NULL;
>     Boolean libdispatchQSafe =
>         pthread_main_np()
>         && (
>             (HANDLE_DISPATCH_ON_BASE_INVOCATION_ONLY && NULL == previousMode)
>            || (!HANDLE_DISPATCH_ON_BASE_INVOCATION_ONLY && 0 == _CFGetTSD(__CFTSDKeyIsInGCDMainQ))
>         );
>     if (
>         libdispatchQSafe
>         && (CFRunLoopGetMain() == rl)
>         && CFSetContainsValue(rl->_commonModes, rlm->_name)
>     )
>         dispatchPort = _dispatch_get_main_queue_port_4CF();
> #endif
> ```

(I have wrapped the original source lines for readability.) Here's what that code does: if it's safe to drain the main queue, and it's the main run loop, and it's a `.common` mode, then `CFRunLoopRun` will check for the main queue being ready to drain. Otherwise, it will not check and so it will not drain the main queue.

The `.common` modes include the tracking modes. So a Combine pipeline that uses `receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)` **will** deliver signals while the user is touching or dragging.

Comment: In my case when `receive(on: RunLoop.main)` and `receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)` doesn't work when dragging and dropping. I am not sure if it is because the notification is being posted on the main thread even without the above. Would `receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)` not work if it is already received in the main thread?

Comment: You should probably post your own question.

Comment: @user1046037 There's another feature of Combine that might be causing your issue: Events are generated by `willSet` property method, so just before a property value is actually updated.  [Here's an explanation](https://www.avanderlee.com/swiftui/published-property-wrapper/#the-importance-of-understanding-the-willset-trigger).

Comment: When using raw low-level runloop/gcd, things are certainly the other way around to what you describe for same calls(2023). Undocumented means prone to be changed at any time, i guess.
Current documentation mentions extra modes that might or might not be accounted for by core methods
```NSApplication defines additional run loop modes, including the following:

    NSModalPanelRunLoopMode

    NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode
```

Comment: “When using raw low-level runloop/gcd”—does that mean, when NOT using the the methods defined by the `Scheduler` protocol from `Combine`? This question and answer are only relevant when using those methods.

Answer (score 33):

I saw the response posted by Roy and thought I could use them interchangeably, but I actually noticed a big difference in my app.

I was loading an image asyncronously in a custom table view cell.
Using `RunLoop.main` would block images from loading as long as the table view was scrolling.

```
  subscriber = NetworkController.fetchImage(url: searchResult.artworkURL)
    .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
    .replaceError(with: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PlaceholderArtwork"))
    .assign(to: \.image, on: artworkImageView)
```

But switching to `DispatchQueue.main` allowed the images to load while it was scrolling.

```
  subscriber = NetworkController.fetchImage(url: searchResult.artworkURL)
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .replaceError(with: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PlaceholderArtwork"))
    .assign(to: \.image, on: artworkImageView)
```

Answer (score 4):

An important caveat of `RunLoop` is that it is "not really thread safe" (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/runloop), so it can be used to delay execution of blocks but not to dispatch them from another thread. If you are doing multithread work (such as loading an image asynchronously) you should be using a `DispatchQueue` to go back to your main UI thread

Comment: Apple docs are inconsistent, because here https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html they recommend using `RunLoop` to dispatch stuff around threads. Since they say two opposite things at the same time, the Apple doc too is not really thread safe...

Comment: @landonepps Not all of the `RunLoop` API is thread-safe, but the methods that give it conformance to `Combine.Scheduler` **are** thread-safe. (The conformance would be nigh-useless otherwise.) The reason your image loading works with `DispatchQueue` but not `RunLoop` is because `RunLoop`'s `Scheduler` conformance schedules blocks to run only in the default run loop mode, but UIKit (and AppKit) run the run loop in a non-default mode while tracking a scroll gesture.

Answer (score 3):

After seeing the replies from [Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77567/rob-mayoff) and [landonepps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1154304/landonepps) I had to test it myself. I also always thought it was interchangeable.

Here is the visible result:

[image]

Here is the source code:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

final class Service {
    var subject = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()
    private let items = Array(1...100)
    
    init() {
        for i in items.indices {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(i)) {
                self.subject.send(self.items[i])
            }
        }
    }
}

final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var runLoopNumbers: [Int] = []
    @Published var dispatchQueueNumbers: [Int] = []
    
    let service = Service()
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        service.subject
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .sink { [weak self] in
                self?.runLoopNumbers.append($0)
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        
        service.subject
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] in
                self?.dispatchQueueNumbers.append($0)
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            HStack {
                VStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Text("RunLoop.main")
                        .font(.headline).bold()
                    ForEach(viewModel.runLoopNumbers, id: \.self) { item in
                        Text("\(item)")
                            .bold()
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                
                Divider()
                
                VStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Text("DispatchQueue.main")
                        .font(.headline).bold()
                    ForEach(viewModel.dispatchQueueNumbers, id: \.self) { item in
                        Text("\(item)")
                            .bold()
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Runloop.main may lose his signal in some cases，such as scrolling.
Most of the time, it's OK to use DispatchQueue.main~

Comment: Please provide some explanation or link to documentation.

Comment: RunLoop.main will not "lose the signal" - execution will be just delayed until the RunLoop switches back to default mode (e.g. when user stops scrolling).