# Why can DispatchQueue.main.async be used as an input source for RunLoop.current.run?

Tags: swift, macos, grand-central-dispatch, event-loop, dispatch-queue

```swift
import Dispatch
import Foundation

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    print("just print in main async")
}

RunLoop.current.run(mode: .default, before: .distantFuture)

print("RunLoop.current.run ends!")
```

[image]

If the runLoop ends after printing "just print in main async", does it means that the runLoop was terminated by main.async (just like an UI event)?

I want to know what exactly happens in this case.

Comment: The documentation of [`DispatchQueue.main`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/1781006-main) says that if you use a run loop on the main thread, the tasks submitted to the main queue will run. Perhaps that could imply that the main queue is an input source.

Answer (score 3):

You asked:

> Why can `DispatchQueue.main.async` be used as an input source for `RunLoop.current.run`?

The behavior you described does not necessarily mean that `DispatchQueue.main.async {…}` is, technically, a runloop “input source”. It only means that the `run(mode:before:)` can allow libDispatch to run dispatched items before returning. We do not have access to these implementation details.

> If the runLoop ends after printing “just print in main async”, does it [mean that the runloop] was terminated by `main.async` (just like an UI event)?

Not necessarily. A few observations:

- Not to split hairs, but it is not “terminated” when you return from `run(before:mode:)`, but rather that it just runs the loop once. It is simply a question of whether it runs the dispatched blocks before returning or not.
- I see slightly different behavior in macOS and iOS targets and where I do this (and whether I did this in an `@IBAction` or `viewDidLoad` or what have you). This makes me even more hesitant to make material assumptions about the implementation details.
- I am seeing race-like behaviors. Consider the following (where I replaced the `print` with “Points of Interest” signposts):

  ```swift
  import UIKit
  import os.log

  let poi = OSLog(subsystem: "Test", category: .pointsOfInterest)

  class ViewController: UIViewController {
      @IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: Any) {
          for i in 0 ..< 10 {
              DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                  print("after")
                  os_signpost(.event, log: poi, name: "After 1 sec", "%d", i)
              }
          }

          for i in 0 ..< 10 {
              DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  print("immediate", i)
                  os_signpost(.event, log: poi, name: "Immediate", "%d", i)
              }
          }

          RunLoop.current.run(mode: .default, before: .distantFuture)

          os_signpost(.event, log: poi, name: "Run")
      }
  }
  ```

  Sometimes I got:

  [image]

  Other times I got:

  [image]

  The former behavior is admittedly hard to reproduce. But races are often hard to manifest.

My bottom line is that I would hesitate to use the term “runloop input source” in conjunction with items dispatched to a queue (without seeing RunLoop source code or some formal assurances from Apple). GCD and runloops are very different tech stacks/patterns. We would generally use GCD (or Swift concurrency or what have you) in lieu of runloop patterns. Furthermore, I would hesitate to rely on a `RunLoop.current.run` to drain the queued items from a dispatch queue.

GCD largely eliminates the need for the legacy runloop `run` (anti)patterns. If the question was purely out of curiosity, then hopefully the above offers some useful observations. But if the runloop is being introduced to achieve some functional behavior in GCD, I might suggest posting a separate question on that broader question and avoid introducing `RunLoop` into the mix.

Comment: From the Threading Programming Guide: "In addition to port-based sources, Cocoa defines a custom input source that allows you to perform a selector on any thread. Like a port-based source, perform selector requests are serialized on the target thread. Unlike a port-based source, a perform selector source removes itself from the run loop after it performs its selector". Isn't this describing a queue? So wouldn't the main queue be considered an custom input source for the run loop?

Comment: That suggests implementation details that I can’t confirm. Is it actually/technically an “input source”? Or is it just doing some behind-the-scenes GCD call to let GCD work items run? I don't know, but not sure if the implementation details matter.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, I think in the provided code, the run loop will end after printing "just print in main async" because of the `DispatchQueue.main.async` block.

As run loop will simply wait for events indefinitely (until an event occurs, because you have provided `.distantFuture`).

At some point, an event occurs, which can be a user interaction event (UI event) or another source getting processed. This event will interrupt the run loop and allow the scheduled `DispatchQueue.main.async` block to execute on the main queue.

Then "just print in main async" will be printed from the asynchronously executed block.

However, after the printed statement there are no more events scheduled, so the run loop will eventually exit and print "RunLoop.current.run ends!".

And hope [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56724566/runloop-vs-dispatchqueue-as-scheduler#:%7E:text=The%20only%20real%20differential%20is,a%20difference%20tween%20the%20two) helps, too.